# Python code failing to execute in Django app

Tags: python, django

In 'App1', I created 'Class1' in models.py. Works just fine.

In 'App2', I created 'Class2' in myfile.py, which inherits from 'Class1'. Works just fine.

In 'App3', I created 'Class3' in myfile.py, which inherits from 'Class1'.

In spite of Class3 being identical to Class2 in all but name and location, the code fails to execute. I know this because I slipped in print statements into App2.myfile.py and App3.myfile.py and, while there was output from App2.myfile.py, there was no output from App3.myfile.py.

Note that the myfile.py files are located in the root of their respective app.

Trying to get to the bottom of the problem, created a new project, copied over App1, App2 and App3 and ran it again. This time there no output from either of the print statements at all and - big surprise - my application stopped working.

1) Why is myfile.py failing to execute?

2) How did I get Project1.App2.myfile.py to execute in the first place???

Update:

The code was described accurately, albeit, implicitly. Below is App2.Class2.myfile.py. The code was stripped down to isolate the problem and the other relevant classes are written the same way.

App2.myfile.py:

```
print 'before App2.Class2'
class Class2
    pass
print 'after App2.Class2'
```

App2 is a very simple project:

- unmodified apps.py file
- models.py file containing one model
- three python files (one of which is myfile.py) defining classes
- empty **init**.py

There's nothing out of the ordinary in the code I wrote so I've omitted it. If you know a reason why specific code would cause such behavior, tell me.

When the development server is run, Project1.App2 outputs 'before App2.Class2' and 'after App2.Class2'. When copied over to Project2. App2 (the same code) produces no output.

Execution method:

1) run python manage.py runserver

2) observe output in Project1:

```
'Performing system checks...

before App2.Class2

after App2.Class2

System check identified no issues'
```

Note the absence of 'before App3.Class2 after App3.Class3'

3) start new Django project (django-admin startproject Project2)

4) copy App1, App2, App3 from Project1 to Project2

5) run (python manage.py runserver)

6) observe output in Project2:

```
'Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues'
```

Comment: How did you execute the file? Can you show the command you used?

Comment: There's no possible way to answer this question. You haven't shown either the code of the "classes" themselves, or even more importantly what is calling them. How are they supposed to be executing?

Comment: Are you sure that execution directory is not changing during import or in your code (you may try to clean out every relative path and replace by absolute one), because Django is used to work with absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Reference the definitions in myfile.py in any app that App2 or App3 does not depend upon to prevent circular references. In models.py:

```
from App2.myfile import Class2
from App3.myfile import Class3
```

This will force Django to recognize your code.

Protip: Stop wasting your time with the collective incompetence of Stack Overflow. You'll spend more time conforming to their ridiculous question protocols than you will fixing your own problems. Just look at the replies to the original question...

This will be my last contribution to your 'commune'-ity.